# How to use curl in bash while loop?

Tags: bash, curl, teamcity

I am new in bash and I have a bash script to check the current server status

```
while "$(curl --user tc-bot:"$TC_BOT_PASSWORD" -X GET "http://teamcity-server:8111/teamcity/app/rest/server/backup")" == "Running"
do
  echo "Backup is running"
  sleep 10
done
```

but I am getting `line 1: Running: command not found.` Curl should return either `Idle` status or `Running` and I have no clues on how to compare curl output with my desired string.

Comment: Use `[[ ... ]]` around your while test expression. `while [[ "aaa" == "bbb" ]]; do ... ; done`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

`while "$(command)" == "Running"`

use

`while [ "$(command)" = "Running" ];`

Note: Prefer `=` over `==` as the former is the POSIX version & compatible with more terminals.